# Using GVim on Windows to edit remote Linux files?

Tags: ssh, debian, vim, x11, putty

Is it possible to use gvim to edit remote Linux files if I am running Windows?

To elaborate, I would like to connect to the Linux server via Putty and then use my local gvim instance to edit the files on the server -- Is this possible?

It seems x11 forwarding (via xming?) might be the solution but I cannot get it to work.

The remote server runs Debian; my local machine is Win7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should fix you up:

```
let g:netrw_cygwin = 0
let g:netrw_ssh_cmd  = '"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" -batch -T -ssh'
let g:netrw_scp_cmd  = '"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe"  -batch -q -scp'
let g:netrw_sftp_cmd = '"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe"  -batch -q -sftp'
```

See `:help netrw-putty` (and lots of scrolling around in that documentation page).

Comment: Hate to comment on such an old thread, but this isn't working on my Win7 install. It's saying the "C:\Program" isn't a valid file.

Comment: @Bryan: try putting plink and pscp on the PATH (like C:\Windows).

Comment: Are you sure you're not on 64 bit Windows? If you are, then it's "Program Files (x86)" rather than "Program Files".

Comment: @Bryan quote just the program files part: c:\"Program Files"\Putty\plink.exe not "c:\program files\putty\plink.exe". And of course adjust location if you are on 64bit windows as ascent1729 said

Comment: I came across this solution using google, and found it incredibly helpful. After adding the excerpt provided to my ~/_vimrc, I was still unable to remotely list directories. You will also want to add the following to list directories [remove the (x86) as necessary]: let g:netrw_list_cmd = '"c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" HOSTNAME ls -Fa'

Comment: How do you get this to work with SSH keys? I've added my ppk to Putty, and am able to connect to my linux server through putty with it, but the netrw stuff in vim just won't work. It will open the file, display it, but then saving it `:w` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what protocol you're using to access the files via putty, but odds are that winscp will support what you want.  [Check out http://winscp.net](http://winscp.net)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, when I need to do this; I open up a local gvim  (A little speedier; I have had issues with x11 forwarding over WAN) and do

```
  :e ftp://<username>@<server>:/<fileToEditRemotePath>
```

You will have to authenticate each time; but works fine for quick edits. On linux; you can use scp rather than ftp; but I'm not sure how to setup the putty forward for that...(Most likely the netrw-putty answer above takes that into consideration, hence I am up voting it)

Answer (score -1):

An officemate of mine used something like this a while back, but I've never tried it.  I prefer to just ssh to the machine in question and fire up vim.

Have you seen [this page](http://fleshy.org.nz/yum/2007/04/03/gvim-and-editing-over-ssh-connections/)?  It seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: The instructions on that page seem to be specific to Linux.

Comment: Have you tried "just ssh[ing] to the machine in question and fir[ing] up vim" from *Windows*? It's not so nice. Doing it in gVim would be so much better.